AttributeError: module 'torch.library' has no attribute 'register_fake'
So I tried implementing this repo: https://github.com/ntnu-ai-lab/SelfPAB on my computer,
I have downloaded the dataset but while i give train, the following issue comes:
File "C:\Users\My PC\Desktop\CCPS\helpmepleaserun\SelfPAB\loo_cross_validation.py", line 3, in <module>
    import train
  File "C:\Users\My PC\Desktop\CCPS\helpmepleaserun\SelfPAB\train.py", line 8, in <module>
    import src.datasets
  File "C:\Users\My PC\Desktop\CCPS\helpmepleaserun\SelfPAB\src\datasets.py", line 11, in <module>
    import src.utils
  File "C:\Users\My PC\Desktop\CCPS\helpmepleaserun\SelfPAB\src\utils.py", line 10, in <module>
    import torchmetrics
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\mynewenv\lib\site-packages\torchmetrics\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from torchmetrics import functional  # noqa: E402
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\mynewenv\lib\site-packages\torchmetrics\functional\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from torchmetrics.functional.audio.pit import permutation_invariant_training, pit_permutate
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\mynewenv\lib\site-packages\torchmetrics\functional\audio\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from torchmetrics.functional.audio.pit import permutation_invariant_training, pit_permutate  # noqa: F401
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\mynewenv\lib\site-packages\torchmetrics\functional\audio\pit.py", line 21, in <module>
    from torchmetrics.utilities.imports import _SCIPY_AVAILABLE 
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\mynewenv\lib\site-packages\torchmetrics\utilities\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from torchmetrics.utilities.checks import check_forward_full_state_property  # noqa: F401
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\mynewenv\lib\site-packages\torchmetrics\utilities\checks.py", line 22, in <module>
    from torchmetrics.utilities.data import select_topk, to_onehot
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\mynewenv\lib\site-packages\torchmetrics\utilities\data.py", line 19, in <module>
    from torchmetrics.utilities.imports import _TORCH_GREATER_EQUAL_1_6, _TORCH_GREATER_EQUAL_1_7, _TORCH_GREATER_EQUAL_1_8     
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\mynewenv\lib\site-packages\torchmetrics\utilities\imports.py", line 117, in <module>
    _TORCHVISION_GREATER_EQUAL_0_8: Optional[bool] = _compare_version("torchvision", operator.ge, "0.8.0")
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\mynewenv\lib\site-packages\torchmetrics\utilities\imports.py", line 79, in _compare_version
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\mynewenv\lib\site-packages\torchvision\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from torchvision import _meta_registrations, datasets, io, models, ops, transforms, utils  # usort:skip
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\mynewenv\lib\site-packages\torchvision\_meta_registrations.py", line 163, in <module>
    @torch.library.register_fake("torchvision::nms")
AttributeError: module 'torch.library' has no attribute 'register_fake'

Anyone know how to rectify this? I have
torch library: 2.5.0.dev20240626 py3.9_cuda12.1_cudnn9_0
i have tried updating torch, but it doesn't make a difference
